# CMake IF condition returns wrong result

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk

I am trying to build native library for android and I need to perform conditional compilation. So I have following code in my CMakeLists.txt file

```
#set (TEST_VAL OFF) #uncomment this to force set this value
option(TEST_VAL "Test my value")
if(NOT ${TEST_VAL} EQUAL OFF)
    message(WARNING "TEST MY VAL IS NOT EQUAL OFF ACTUAL VALUE: ${DISABLE_SSE} ")
else ()
    message(WARNING "TEST MY VAL IS ON ACTUAL VALUE: ${DISABLE_SSE} ")
endif()
```

As you see I am trying to get option value and compile the library.

This is how I provide this option (build.gradle) file.

```
android {
   ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                // Passes optional arguments to CMake.
                arguments "-DTEST_VAL=OFF" 
            }
        }

   ...
}
```

But in my output I see only:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:35 (message): TEST MY VAL IS NOT EQUAL OFF ACTUAL VALUE: OFF
```

So how It could that with OFF value it is not equal to OFF?
What I am I doing wrong.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you @john it was actually a type in question. The main problem if I set the value explicitly using set (TEST_VAL OFF) I have the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EQUAL` operator is "true if the given string or variable’s value is a valid number and equal to that on the right."

So just do `if (NOT TEST_VAL)` because just giving the variable's name is "true if the constant is 1, ON, YES, TRUE, Y, or a non-zero number."

**If you can't change the code or raise an issue ...**

I've run some tests and the following does work:

```
set(TEST_VAL OFF)
set(OFF 0)

if(NOT ${TEST_VAL} EQUAL OFF)
    message(STATUS "NOT \${TEST_VAL} EQUAL OFF")
endif()
```

Since `EQUAL` needs a number for comparison you can define the string `OFF` to `0`.

So in your examples that would be equivalent to `arguments "-DTEST_VAL=OFF -DOFF=0"`.

**Reference**

- [`if()` command documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html)

Comment: Thank you but this code of the library which I can not modify. I just trying to figure out how to disable not needed option

Comment: @SergeyPekar Do we talk about [this](https://github.com/strukturag/libde265/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L41) library? Have you tried `set(TEST_VAL OFF CACHE INTERNAL "")`? Because options are cached variables and `INTERNAL` would force the value.

Comment: it is proprietary library but I tried to compile [that](https://github.com/strukturag/libde265/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L41) library and it seems it have same issue.

Comment: @SergeyPekar Ok, the `EQUAL` check just does not work with strings. So I've run some test and added an solution to my answer.